# 自分のサーバーに外部からHTTPでアクセスしたいが、できない

Tags: network

自分のPC上に立てたサーバーに外部からHTTPでアクセスしたいのですが、接続が拒否されます。
サーバーは起動しているのですが、WAN側IPアドレスを指定してアクセスしようとするとrefused to connectと言われてしまいます。
どういう可能性があるか教えていただけないでしょうか。

構成は以下の通りです。

### [image: 構成]

外部のネットワークに繋いだPCのブラウザからアクセスしたく色々試したところ、以下のことが分かりました。
- 外部PCからルーターのWAN側IPアドレスへのPNIG: 不可(communication prhibited by filter)
- 外部PCのブラウザからWAN側IPアドレスにアクセス：不可(`10.97.***.***:80` へのアクセスがrefued to connect)
- サーバーのPCからWAN側IPアドレスへのPING:可(PING `10.97.***.***` はOK)
- サーバーのPCのブラウザからWAN側IPアドレスへのアクセス:不可(`10.97.***.***:80` へのアクセスがrefued to connect)
- サーバーのPCのブラウザからLAN側IPアドレスへのアクセス:可(`192.168.100.100:80` へのアクセス OK)

Comment: やりたいことはわかりましたが、それを実現するべくどのような設定を行ったかを記載してください。まさか念じただけではありませんよね？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ルータの外側のアドレスが10.97.***.***なので、プロバイダが配布しているのはプライベートアドレスです。インターネットからアクセスすることは出来ません。

(プロバイダが内部宛てトラフィックをNATしてくれれば別ですが、聞いたことないです)

Answer (score 0):

記載の事項から推測できるのは以下のことと考えます。

- PINGが`communication prhibited by filter`とエラーになっているので、ICMPに対し、ルータを含むWAN側ネットワーク(の機器)でアクセス制御がかかっている。(※これは解決しなくてもいいかもしれない)
- 外部PCからのHTTPアクセスが`refued to connect`とエラーになっているので、ルータもしくはサーバPC(MAC)の80番ポートがLISTEN状態になっていない。

後者の切り分けを行うには、LAN内に別のPCを設置し、`http://192.168.100.100`にアクセスできるか確認するのがよいと思います。
あるいは、MACであればtcpdumpも可能なので、tcpdumpで80番ポートにパケットが到着しているか確認する方法もあると思います。(到着している場合RSTが戻っていないことも確認)

LANの別のPCからhttpアクセスできるのであれば、ルータのフォワード(NAT)設定がおかしい、アクセスできないのであれば、サーバの設定がおかしいと判断できると思います。